# understanding a Build c++

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I think I know what a build is. But I am not sure. My definition of a build is another word for saying compiled application. Can someone please tell me what exactly a build is. And why do people ask for 3 types of builds. Such as Debug Build, Profile Build and a Release Build. What are the differences.

[edit]
the types of builds

Comment: "And why do people ask for 2 types of builds. Such as Debug Build, Profile Build and a Release Build.": these look like 3 types to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Visual Studio Debug and Release Modes](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebugRelease.aspx)

**Release Mode**

When an assembly is built in release mode, the compiler performs all available optimisations to ensure that the outputted executables and libraries execute as efficiently as possible. This mode should be used for completed and tested software that is to be released to end-users. The drawback of release mode is that whilst the generated code is usually faster and smaller, it is not accessible to debugging tools.

**Debug Mode**

Debug mode is used whilst developing software. When an assembly is compiled in debug mode, additional symbolic information is embedded and the code is not optimised. This means that the output of the compiler is generally larger, slower and less efficient. However, a debugger can be attached to the running program to allow the code to be stepped through whilst monitoring the values of internal variables.

Answer (score 3):

A build means basically doing a set of tasks to make your program.  The main components of a typical build is compiling and linking.

More specifically a build can contain compiling, linking, setting version numbers, copying outputs to some location,  creating an installer and anything else.

When people say debug or release build or etc., they may have different settings defined for each.  For example in a debug build you will create program database files for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

A build does not have to include only compiled and linked targets. Usually there is at least one of those, but a "build" could also include creating plain-text or binary files, moving images, sounds, and other files into the correct places to be accessed by the file, or any other operation that needs to be performed for the application to run.

The multiple types of builds are made to target different "audiences", if you will. For instance, and end-user does not need to collect information about what functions were called or how many times and exception was raised, or any other diagnostic info (though that information is valuable to developers). Usually the final "release" build is made to be fast and small, and not load the user down with extras like that.